# SQL Unique ID for union all - Sybase

Tags: sql, union, sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

Is it possible to generate a unique ID for the auxiliary table? I am retrieving data from several tables, but I do not know how to create a new ID for the results:

I would like to have an additional column with ID.

I tried to look for several methods, but nothing helped me.
I will be very grateful.

Greetings,

```
with ct as (
      select *
      INTO temp_table
from dba.view_NEW_Users_AreaCodes ur
     join dba.view_NEW_Customers_SalesTowns ct on ct.CustSalesTerritoryTTID = ur.UserAreaCodeID
where ur.UserType = 'TT'
      and ct.CustSalesTerritoryTTID <> 0
union all
select *
from dba.view_NEW_Users_AreaCodes ur
     join dba.view_NEW_Customers_SalesTowns ct on ct.CustSalesTerritoryMTID = ur.UserAreaCodeID
where ur.UserType = 'MT'
      and ct.CustSalesTerritoryMTID <> 0
union all
select *
from dba.view_NEW_Users_AreaCodes ur
     join dba.view_NEW_Customers_SalesTowns ct on ct.CustSalesTerritoryHRCID = ur.UserAreaCodeID
where ur.UserType = 'HRC'
      and ct.CustSalesTerritoryHRCID <> 0
union all
select *
from dba.view_NEW_Users_AreaCodes ur
     join dba.view_NEW_Customers_SalesTowns ct on ct.CustSalesTerritoryDevID = ur.UserAreaCodeID
where ur.UserType = 'DEV'
      and ct.CustSalesTerritoryDevID <> 0
     )
select row_number() over (order by newid()) as DATA_ID,
       ct.*
from ct;
```

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?

Comment: @markp-fuso

SQL Anywher 10.0.1
Sybase Central 5.0.0.3

Comment: the question has been updated to use  Gordon's `newid()` recommendation; what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `row_number()`:

```
with t as (
      < your query here >
     )
select row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum,
       t.*
from t;
```

`newid()` is just an arbitrary value that randomizes the numbering.  You can use a column there if you prefer a more canonical ordering.

Comment: After 2 minutes, it receives information that the table "t" not found "

Comment: How do I export everything to a table? I added after SELECT 

 INTO #temp. Thank you for help :)

Comment: @MichałZawada . . . `t` is the name of the CTE.  It is quite well-defined in the query.